# Raise KeyError for my Slack bot in Python

Tags: python, slack

I am trying to create a simple bot for slack. But for whatever reason, I keep getting the error:

> & C:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe
> c:/Users/myname/OneDrive/Documents/Python/bot.py Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File "c:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Documents\Python\bot.py",
> line 9, in 
> client = slack.WebClient(token=os.environ["SLACK_TOKEN"])   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py",
> line 679, in **getitem**
> raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'SLACK_TOKEN'

I am not sure why. I tried many different things, and keep getting this error.
My code:

```
import slack
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

client = slack.WebClient(token=os.environ["SLACK_TOKEN"])

client.chat_postMessage(channel='#operations', text="Hello World!")
```

and in a .env:

```
SLACK_TOKEN="tokentokentoken" python myapp.py
```

I checked Slack guide, I checked online, but nothing I found works.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: If you run your app as `SLACK_TOKEN=abc python myapp.py`, `myapp.py` should be able to get the env variable by just calling `os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN']`. No dotenv/load_dotenv necessary.

Comment: that unfortunately did not change anything. (P.S. Do you mind redacting the token, please?

Comment: Please show the output of `print(os.environ)` placed after your import statements or `load_dotenv` call

Comment: Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Razer Chroma SDK\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Razer Chroma SDK\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Razer\\ChromaBroadcast\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Razer\\ChromaBroadcast\\bin;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA

Comment: Please [edit] the post, not as a comment

Comment: As you can see, though, `'SLACK_TOKEN'` is not in the output

Comment: I see that, but I do not understand why.